# How to use templates with C++/CLI 2010?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, visual-c++-2010

I've got following method in c#:

```
    public static T[] GetResult<T>(ulong taskId)
    {
        return GetResult(taskId).Cast<T>().ToArray();
    }
```

and I'm trying to use it in managed c++ 2010 like this:

```
array<UrlInfo^>^ arr=Scheduler::GetResult<UrlInfo>(taskId);
```

where I'm getting

```
Error   3   error C2770: invalid explicit generic argument(s) for 
'cli::array<Type,dimension>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `UrlInfo` is a value type, you don't want the `^`.

Try

```
array<UrlInfo>^ arr
```

If `UrlInfo` is a reference type, you need a `^` when calling `GetResult`.

```
arr=Scheduler::GetResult<UrlInfo^>(taskId);
```

Either way something's wrong.  Based on the error message, I think it's the first case.

Comment: oh my. How could I had make such a mistake). I guess, c# habits die hard! Thanks