# error C2770: invalid explicit generic argument(s)

Tags: c#, generics, c++-cli

I am trying to adapt an API example from Point Grey's new Spinnaker API to work with an existing flycapture 2 c++/CLI program by going line for line and translating into c++/cli.  However I get completely stuck here:

```
IEnum iAcquisitionMode = nodeMap.GetNode<IEnum>("AcquisitionMode");
```

I thought this would become:

```
IEnum ^iAcquisitionMode = nodeMap->GetNode<IEnum>("AcquisitionMode");
```

But VS throws:

> error C2770: invalid explicit generic argument(s) for 'NodeType SpinnakerNET::GenApi::INodeMap::GetNode(System::String ^)'

I'm not too familiar with c# syntax, so it's unclear to me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: [Not sure if this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057565/how-to-use-templates-with-c-cli-2010)

Comment: That was the solution, thanks.  Too much staring back and forth between c# and CLI.

Answer (score 2):

The correct line would be:

```
IEnum ^iAcquisitionMode = nodeMap->GetNode<IEnum ^>("AcquisitionMode");
```

Where the IEnum needs a ^ because it is a handle to a managed object and not the object itself.  Thank you to john for the solution.